# How can I access MySQL on a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, database-connection

I have deployed MySQL in my Kubernetes cluster. It works fine. But I am not aware of how to access or connect the MySQL service to other applications. I found that MySQL deployment is not browser-supported.
When I call the MySQL server on the browser using `IP:nodeport`, I found the following error:

```
J���
5.7.37����!bo.;�ÿÿ�ÿÁ����������rBPvNbCJ�mysql_native_password�!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order
```

I can access the MySQL server through Kubernetes dashboard's pod shell using the MySQL user and password.

Comment: If you want to use it through a browser then install some software that allows you to do so. Databases aren’t web servers or applications

Comment: @ashique Please improve your question. It's not clear which connection you mean, since from the title "how can i access" and then in the question "how to access or connect MySQL service to other applications". So, what is the real purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can try deploying the MySQL client on Kubernetes and connect using it.

MySQL client like : Adminer, phpMyadmin etc

Adminer example :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: adminer
  labels:
    app: adminer
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: adminer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: adminer
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: adminer
          image: adminer:4.6.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: ADMINER_DESIGN
              value: "pappu687"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: adminer-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: adminer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

You can expose this deployment with service type **Nodeport** or **Port forwarding**.

```
kubectl port-forward svc/adminer-svc 8080:8080
```

Open the `localhost:8080`

Once the service is exposed you can access the UI in the browser and from there you can access the MySQL database over the **service name**.

Read more about adminer : https://www.adminer.org/